# WCF Inheritance/Polymorphism and Serialization

Tags: wcf, datacontractserializer

I have a class, `ReportDef`, which is a concrete class that I've decorated with `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes as needed.  `ReportDef` is in assembly `A1` along with my `ServiceContract`, `IReportService`.  I then have another class, `UiReportDef`, which derives from `ReportDef` and is in assembly `A2`.  `UiReportDef` has no additional state that the service cares about.

I want to invoke my service with an instance of `UiReportDef`.  Is there any way (short of manually constructing a `ReportDef` instance from `UiReportDef`) to do this without having my service know about `A2`?  I know about `KnownType`.  I don't want to reference `A2`.

---

**EDIT:** Here's some context that might make my question easier to understand. My `ServiceContract` implements `IReportService` which defines a method, `RunReport(ReportDef report)`.  `ReportDef` is decorated with the `DataContract` attribute, and has private members decorated with `DataMember`.  `UiReportDef` is in an assembly that depends on UI-related assemblies, etc. I didn't design the existing class hierarchy.  I need to pass `ReportDefs` and `UiReportDefs` (as `ReportDefs`) to the new service.  Since `ReportDef` is concrete, I would expect the serializer to treat `UiReportDefs` as `ReportDefs` in the absence of any other information.

Comment: For now, I'm adding a constructor to the base class that takes an instance of itself and copyies the relevant state.  Very ugly but I need to move on.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't understand you question.

But I think I understand part of it now, you want to deserialize an object in an assembly that has no reference to it?

If so, you can't unless you're willing to do a whole lot of reflection and keep it defined/referenced as "object"

The common way to do this and was trying to explain in my previous answer is that you should use an interface that can be referenced by both client/server.

It is common practice to create stub assemblies consisting of nothing but interfaces for this case.

Or as your comment on your question suggests, you can use DTO objects. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Transfer_Object

Comment: That doesn't work because the run-time type of the object is unchanged by a cast.

Answer (score 1):

This thread may probably help a lot : [WCF Inheritance and DataContract](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/dd9adca0-7422-4d51-bd79-487dafe3386d/)

Answer (score -3):

WCF is not polymorphic because its not object oriented. Hence this is not possible.

Comment: ?
Why -1? I did answer your question.

Comment: Yeah, this was to Deviant. I dont know what was this - getting rid of comeptition by downwoting my answer? Especially considering his answer is wrong.

Comment: I am right. It is not possible, I also explained why. And it makes sense to everyone else.